# Лайкнул ли пользователь пост?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Python3.6, Django2.0, Postgres.

У меня есть страница, где отображаются статьи из базы данных.
Эти статьи можно лайкать аутентифицированному пользователю.

Чего я хочу: чтобы при отображении этой страницы, под каждой статьей было написано, что пользователь эту статью лайкнул или нет.

Модель Like у меня описана так:

```
class Like(models.Model):

article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comment_id = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Я сделал попытку отдавать то, что мне нужно, таким образом:

```
articles = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date').annotate(
        is_liked=Case(
            When(like__user_id_id=self.request.user.id, then=True),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
    )
```

И на первый взгляд все показалось рабочим, однако при тестировании на лайках от нескольких пользователей получился баг:
статьи отдаются из базы данных столько раз (дублируются), сколько и лайков на этой статье. И это ужасно. И distinct() здесь не поможет, потому что одна статья отдается с is_liked=True, а остальные нет.И 1 дубль всегда будет жить.

Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, сами модели не очень удачные у вас получились. На вашем месте, я бы впринципе убрал модель Like и сделал, бы что-то вроде:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # поля с информацией о стате
    likes = models.BigIntegerField() # количество лайков
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User) # кто лайкал
```

Можно впринципе хранить только liked_users, а количество лайков определять через `len(Article.objects.get(id=..).liked_users.all())`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это менее эффективнее будет работать, в любом случае проверьте сами, возможно django оптимизирует такой запрос, чтобы на уровне бд не вытаскивать все записи, а просто применить агрегатную функцию count и вернуть только число.

А по поводу как проверить лайкал ли юзер статью, можно так:

```
if Article.objects.get(id=..).liked_users.filter(id=user.id).exists():
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще некуда

```
{% if obj.user %}
   Юзер {{ obj.user }} лайкнул
{% else %}
   Не лайкнул
{% endif %}
```